# Simple integration just learning this application

Tags: integration

I want to integrate a function as $f(x)=\sin^{-1}x$. What should be the proper method of doing it?

Comment: Integration by parts, $u=\arcsin x$, $dv=dx$.

Comment: Andre Nicolas has given the correct approach. Note that this same trick is used in a number of other integrals where you just don't seem to have anything to "reach for" in the integrand, such as $\int \arctan(x) dx$ and $\int \ln(x) dx$.

Comment: There is kind of a way, that sort of sneaks around integration by parts. "Guess" that the answer is $x\arcsin x$. To check we have the right answer, differentiate. OOps, we get $\arcsin x+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. How can we adjust our guess?

Comment: @AndréNicolas ya thats true but how to guess? As i am a student...in exam paper i can't guess like this in all questions..

Comment: The integration by parts approach is the standard way to do it.  For exams, you absolutely need to know integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, use integration by parts as follows $$\int \sin^{-1}(x)\ dx=\int \sin^{-1}(x)\cdot 1\ dx$$
$$=\sin^{-1}(x)\int 1\ dx-\int \left(\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{-1}(x))\cdot \int 1\ dx\right)\ dx$$
$$=\sin^{-1}(x)\cdot(x)-\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdot (x)\ dx$$
$$=x\sin^{-1}(x)+\frac 12\int \frac{(-2x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$$
$$=x\sin^{-1}(x)+\frac 12\int (1-x^2)^{-1/2}d(1-x^2)$$
$$=x\sin^{-1}(x)+\frac 12\cdot \frac{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}{1/2}+C$$
$$=\color{red}{x\sin^{-1}(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}+C}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can do it integration by parts method as taking f(x)= sin and f(x)2 = 1.

Also we can take x=sin(t) as second method.

My maths is this level i can solve this sum like this only..but i want a method that we can use directly.

Comment: Please use LaTeX. As stated in previous comments, there is no direct way - you need to use integration by parts in order to integrate $\sin^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: There is no "direct" approach with integrals in general. Many very simple-looking functions have very complicated antiderivatives, or even antiderivatives that are not given by elementary functions at all. That said, both of your suggested methods work: $x=\sin(t)$ gives $dx=\cos(t) dt$ so you have $\int t \cos(t) dt$. But then, all you've really done is changed the integral into a form where it is more obvious that integration by parts will help.

Comment: But i want another method of it..i know method of integration by parts

Comment: @user5899719 There is no method that is not essentially integration by parts. The "guess" method suggested by Andre Nicolas under the OP is integration by parts in disguise.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could try is substituting $x=\sin t$, so that $\mathrm{d}x=\cos t\,\mathrm{d}t$.
$$\int\sin^{-1}x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int t\cos t\,\mathrm{d}t$$
If you can find a way to integrate this without using integration by parts, then more power to you.

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts is *the* method for this one, but here is another way of thinking (I don't say it is really different from integration by parts, and I don't suggest to use this instead of integration by parts).

Let us think of $0<x<1$. Draw the graph of $y=\arcsin x$.

[image: arcsin]

From the fundamental theorem of calculus we know that $x\mapsto \int_0^x\arcsin t\,dt$ is a primitive of $x\mapsto\arcsin x$. From the area interpretation of integrals and from the figure, we find that (both sides correspond to the area of the rectangle)
$$
\int_0^{\arcsin x}\sin t\,dt+\int_0^x \arcsin t\,dt=x\arcsin x.
$$
Thus, using the fundamental theorem (the version with insertion of limits) on the integral with integrand $\sin t$ (which is easy to find a primitive to), we get 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^x\arcsin t\,dt&=x\arcsin x-\bigl[-\cos t\bigr]_0^{\arcsin x}\\
&=x\arcsin x+\cos(\arcsin x)-1\\
&=x\arcsin x+\sqrt{1-x^2}-1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here we have used the fact that (in the given domain) $\cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin x)}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. We conclude that (invoking the $-1$ into the arbitrary constant $C$)
$$
\int \arcsin x\,dx=x\arcsin x+\sqrt{1-x^2}+C.
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

When integrating by parts in the middle a stage comes to integrate

$$ \int \frac{x\, dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$

$$= \dfrac12 \int \frac{2 x\, dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}= \dfrac12 \int \frac{d\,(x^2) }{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

which  can be integrated with $ x^2 = u$ substitution or directly.